# Loop only over a specific set of range of cells in a spreadsheet in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a column to loop and check for a value, the challenge is that the data starts from but not a specific end cell.

Let's say, the data always starts from `B4` but may end at any cell in the Column B.

| Column B |
| --- |
| Type 1 |
| Type 2 |
| Type 3 |
| Type 4 |
| Type 5 |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |

I want to loop starting from B4 and read cells down below until it finds an empty cell and the loop should break out.

I wanted to read cell values of the whole range and the do an `If - else` check, but was thinking of a more easy way to do.

Please help!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all non-blank values in column `B`, use this pattern:

```
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange('B1:B')
    .getValues()
    .flat()
    .filter(String);
```

This gives you a 1D array that is easy to process with `Array.map()`, `Array.forEach()` and the like.